# Odd Behavior Deleting a record from a stated array in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the following technique to delete an object from an array that is in state:

```
export default function App() {
  const [gridData, setGridData] = useState({field1:"Placeholder",data:[]});

  const data = [
    { numstart: 1,numend: 1,description: "Wine - Taylors Reserve",rate: 83.3},
    { numstart: 2, numend: 2, description: "Hot Choc Vending", rate: 3.07 },
    { numstart: 3, numend: 3, description: "Absolut Citron", rate: 75.65 },
    { numstart: 4, numend: 4, description: "Flour - Strong", rate: 33.16 },    
  ];

  const delData = (ndx) => {
    let newList = [...gridData.data];
    newList.splice(ndx,1)
    console.log(newList)
    setGridData(ps=>({...ps,data:[...newList]}));
  };

  useEffect(() => setGridData(ps=>({...ps,data:data})), []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => delData(1)}>Delete Hot Choc Vending</button>
      <p>Current Descritpion at Record 2: {gridData.data[1].description}</p>
      <p>Current Record Count: {gridData.data.length}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

What is happening is the correct record is being removed from `newList`, but when I set the state and view the modification, it shows that the LAST record in the array was removed and not the record that was removed in `newList`

*** EDIT ***
OK, @Bergi may be on to something with it rendering.  Looks like that may be the issue - revamped code which works correctly:

```
export default function App() {
  const [gridData, setGridData] = useState([
    {numstart: 1,numend: 1,description: "Wine - Taylors Reserve",rate: 83.3},
    { numstart: 2, numend: 2, description: "Hot Choc Vending", rate: 3.07 },
    { numstart: 3, numend: 3, description: "Absolut Citron", rate: 75.65 },
    { numstart: 4, numend: 4, description: "Flour - Strong", rate: 33.16 },
    { numstart: 5, numend: 5, description: "Cauliflower", rate: 33.37 },
    { numstart: 6, numend: 6, description: "Appetizer - Seafood Assortment",rate: 10.7},
    { numstart: 7, numend: 7, description: "Lemonade - Island Tea, 591 Ml", rate: 84.91}
  ]);
  const delData = (ndx) => {
    setGridData((ps) => ps.filter((_, index) => index !== ndx));
  };

  const buildRows = () => {
    return gridData.map((r, rndx) => {
      return (
        <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
          <button onClick={() => delData(rndx)}>Delete</button>
          <div>
            <input id={`desc-${rndx.toString()}`} value={r.description} />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });
  };
  return <div className="App">{buildRows()}</div>;
}
```

Here's the odd thing:  If I set:

`<input id={`desc-${rndx.toString()}`} value={r.description} />`

to

`<input id={`desc-${rndx.toString()}`} defaultValue={r.description} />`

The code breaks.  Leaving the input with a defaultValue causes the issue of deleting the last object in the array.

So in my case it has to do with the defaltValue vs value attribute on the input.

Comment: So `delStart(1)` means you want to delete the object with index 1 from the `gridData` ?

Comment: @DanteDX Correct.  It would delete the object with the description "Hot Choc Vending"

Comment: and `numstart` and `numend` of an object will be equal to the index of that particular object as well ?

Comment: No, they just part of the object.  I want to delete the object at index n.  Instead the last object in the array gets deleted.

Comment: That `useEffect` doesn't make a lot of sense. Why not just initialise your state with the `const data`?

Comment: Are you actually rendering the `gridData` into a grid somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I am, but I didn't think that was part of the issue. I am examining the vars in console.

Comment: I am comparing the arrays in console so it's not a rendering issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is always recommended that when you need to update a state variable in React by modifying its previous value, you should use the **previousValue** parameter provided in the **setState** method.

This method guarantees you are always getting the latest value even though the actual state variable might not have been updated yet since the **setState** operation is asynchronous.

Having said that, you can make your code work by changing your implementation like this:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [gridData, setGridData] = useState({field1:"Placeholder",data:[]});

  const data = [
    { numstart: 1,numend: 1,description: "Wine - Taylors Reserve",rate: 83.3},
    { numstart: 2, numend: 2, description: "Hot Choc Vending", rate: 3.07 },
    { numstart: 3, numend: 3, description: "Absolut Citron", rate: 75.65 },
    { numstart: 4, numend: 4, description: "Flour - Strong", rate: 33.16 },    
  ];

  const delData = (ndx) => {
    setGridData((prevGridData) => {
      const newList = prevGridData.data.filter((item, index) => index !== ndx);
      return { ...prevGridData, data: newList };
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => setGridData(ps=>({...ps,data:data})), []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => delData(1)}>Delete Hot Choc Vending</button>
      <p>Current Descritpion at Record 2: {gridData.data[1].description}</p>
      <p>Current Record Count: {gridData.data.length}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same thing I did, just a different way?  I tried it and it is still deleteing the last record in the array.

Comment: The const data is test data and will be removed.  I am using it to try and figure out why the setState is not setting the array properly. Th real data will be assigned with useEffect

Comment: I have edited my answer with an alternative solution. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Still deleting the last object in the array.  I have verified the correct ndx and in my original post view the value of `newList` which verifies the correct record was deleted.  Once I set the state the updated array shows the deleted object but the last object in the array is missing.

Comment: I see, this happens with the first click of the Delete button? And what do you expect to see after clicking this button?

Comment: If I click the delete button it should remove the object containing the description  "Hot Choc Vending" .  In my original post I examine `newList` and it, indeed, shows that the correct object was deleted.  After I set the state and examine `gridState.data`, the data object with the description "Flour Strong" is deleted but "Hot Choc Vending" is still there.

Comment: Btw, no point in spreading `newList` into an array literal, `newList` already is a new array

Comment: I'm trying everyway I can think of to get this to work.